# How can I write this in one line?

Tags: python

Hey So I'm working on a problem that asks me to manipulate a dictionary by grabbing all the keys and values and formatting them into a single string for every key/value pair. I have to do this in one line, or so I think, the problem is better explained in the image.[image]

Comment: Have you tried anything yet?

Comment: Nothing really I'm brand new to Python I don't even know where to start. I know I have to write a loop and guessing since that last line with the `print()` is indented that's whats inside the loop. I think I just have to write the head of the loop. I know I can get the countries by doing `for country in country_pop.keys():` and I can grab the population by `for pop in country_pop.values():`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe they would like you to write `for country, pop in country_pop.items():` on line 7. However, you can do the entire thing in one line as well.

```
print('\n'.join([f'{key} has {value} people' for key, value in country_pop.items()]))
```

Comment: Why are you booing me? I'm right.

Comment: doesn't work there is already a print() provided I just need to write the head of the loop. You see how the last line of code is indented. That is the body of the for loop, I need to write the head of it and it has to grab each key and the corresponding value then print it out

Comment: Yes I gave two answers. First, what to write on line 7. Then underneath how to write it in 1 line instead of 2.

Comment: Oh Sorry didn't see that. This worked thank you!